# How to generate the highest number from one column in mysql database with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I hope you can help me with this. I have a column in my database called lno which is shortcut for license number. That number basically increase by one every time new license is added to my database. To make life easier for myself Im trying to create button that will generate next available license number which of course will be the highest existing+1. here is my php code:

```
  if($nextlic){
global $lno,$rec;


    $query= mysql_query ( "SELECT MAX(lno)+1 FROM mlicense_table  ");
    $rec = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $lno = $rec['lno'];//serial number
    mysql_free_result($query);
    $message="Successful";

}
```

and simple html for my button:

```
   <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="nextlic" value="Next available      
    license" /></td>
```

These two keeps coming up and number is not generated

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\license_db\miramo2.php on line 431

Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\license_db\miramo2.php on line 433

Can anyone give me advice on what Im doing wrong? Im still so new to it. Thanks

Comment: mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Apart from the above comment, are you getting a mysql error? Try `mysql_query ( "SELECT MAX(lno)+1 FROM mlicense_table  ") or die(mysql_error());` to see if your query is the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is caused by an error in your query. Maybe a column or table that doesn't exist. Use `var_dump(mysql_error())` to find out what's going on there.

However once you get that working you will have other problems. Your array will look like this:

```
array(1) {
    ["MAX(lno)+1"] => 12345
}
```

This means you would have to refer to `$lno = $rec['MAX(lno)+1'];`.

That's a headache, so just make it easer:

```
$rec = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$lno = $rec[0];
```

EDIT:

> That number basically increase by one every time new license is added to my database

Then what's wrong with setting `lno` to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: Thanks a million Niet... All sorted, replaced my lines with the one you suggested and found mistake by calling var_dump(mysql_error()). Works perfectly. Im so relieved. Thanks to everyone else too. Have a good day guys

Comment: Dont do it this way. As this answer also says, you should make lno the primary key and auto increment. If you dont do this, think about what happens when this script is called by 2 users at the exact same time (highly unlikely probably, but definately possible). They would both be given the same license number, and that's not good! And also the more efficent query would be "SELECT lno FROM mlicense_table ORDER BY lno desc LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 
$query= mysql_query ( "SELECT MAX(lno)+1 as lno FROM mlicenses_table  ");

in place of 
$query= mysql_query ( "SELECT MAX(lno)+1 FROM mlicenses_table  ");

Answer (score 0):

So this is one beautiful piece that works now

```
 if($nextlic){
global $lno,$rec;


    $query= mysql_query ( "SELECT MAX(lno)+1 FROM mlicenses_table  ");
    var_dump(mysql_error());
    $rec = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $lno = $rec[0];
    mysql_free_result($query);
    $message="Successful";

}
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: It sounds to me like your whole approach is back-to-front, but hey, it's your party.